# Remove addListener (Event from Google Analytics) from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am launching an event to google analytics every time the user chooses a different `select` option. But when the user clicks again on the `select` event is fired again. I'm trying to remove the element event after the user chooses the option. I've tried `unbind()` and `off()` but is not working. Can anyone help me please?

JS:

```
$('#estado').change(function(){
     var getEstado = $('#estado option:selected').val();
     var getEstadoDesc = $('#estado option:selected').text();

     var homeEstado = document.getElementById('estado');
     addListener(homeEstado, 'click', function() {
         ga('send', 'event', 'Busca', 'Estado', getEstadoDesc);
         removeEventHandler(homeEstado, 'click');
     });

     function addListener(element, type, callback) {
        if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
        else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
     }

     function removeEventHandler(element, type, callback) {
         if (element.removeEventListener) element.removeEventListener(type,callback);
         else if (element.detachEvent) element.detachEvent('on' + type, callback); 
     }

     $.ajax({  
         type: 'POST',
         data: {estado: getEstado},
         url: './ajax/get_cidade.php',
         beforeSend: function(data){

         },
         success: function(data){
             $('#load-cursos').html(data);
         },
     });
 });
```

Comment: Try `$('#estado').off('change')`?

Comment: Tried, it continues with the issue.

Comment: What you want to stop listening is to stop `ga('send', 'event', 'Busca', 'Estado', getEstadoDesc);` ?

Comment: can you try $('#estado').unbind('change') or $('#estado').removeAttr('change')?

Comment: @fuyushimoya yes, when you select the option, triggers the event and then remove the Listener. Because clicking back to select even without selecting an option the event will fire again.

Comment: Then I think you should detach the event which was added by your `addListener` after ga(...) is called. `$('#estado').unbind()` will remove the change event on select, which is just retrieve the options data for you, I believe its not what you want to remove?

Comment: @fuyushimoya yes, it is exactly this event I want to remove. But the `unbind()` does not work, neither the `off()`. I am also trying to `removeEventListener()` and `detachEvent()` but it seems that do not work well.

Comment: Ugh, I mean in pseudo, create a `removeListener` just use same param as `addListener`, then call `removeListener(homeEstado, 'click')` right after `ga(....`

Comment: @fuyushimoya I updated the code above.

Comment: No, it continues with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just make a alter to your code, please see if that is what you want.

```js
var selecEvent = function(){
    var getEstado = $('#estado option:selected').val();
    var getEstadoDesc = $('#estado option:selected').text();
    
    function addListener(element, type, callback) {
        if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
        else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
    }
     function removeListener(element, type, callback) {
        if (element.addEventListener) element.removeEventListener(type, callback);
        else if (element.attachEvent) element.detachEvent('on' + type, callback);
    }

    var homeEstado = document.getElementById('estado');
    var sendFunction = function() {
        alert('Selected ' + getEstadoDesc + ' with value ' + getEstado);
        removeListener(homeEstado, 'click',  sendFunction);
    };
    
    addListener(homeEstado, 'click',  sendFunction);
    
    // Stop listen to any changes to prevent multiple ajax call and alerts... etc.
    $('#estado').off();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Select changed');
        // Now every thing done. Event sent, content load, we can listen to select again.
        $('#estado').change(selecEvent);
    }, 3000);
 }

$('#estado').change(selecEvent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="estado">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

removeListener or detachEvent, form document, needs a function to remove, so I have to alter the execute ga to a simple alert function. And altered ajax to a settimeout to simulate ajax delay.

Take to look to see if I misunderstood something?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions worked, I had to use an alternate route. Hidden a `div`, and whenever there is a `change` in the `select` an element is added to the `div` activating a `trigger` and firing my `event`. Either way thank you.